# Getting array index out of bound exception from StoredProcedure.execute()?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am stuck with an exception on a Java/Spring application. I hope someone can help.

I have extended `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` for an Oracle function called.

```
public class CreateBookingFunction extends StoredProcedure {
    public CreateBookingFunction(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String procName){
        // initialise function.
        super(jdbcTemplate, procName);
        setFunction(true);
        // function return.
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("po_result", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
        // input parameters bookingid, presenter array, booking date array, event mail object.
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("pi_booking",OracleTypes.STRUCT,"BOOKING_TYP"));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("pi_presenters",OracleTypes.ARRAY,"PERSON_TBL_TYP"));
        // function result DBResult object.
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("po_return",OracleTypes.STRUCT,"RETURN_TYP",new SqlReturnSqlData(SQLDBResult.class)));
        allowsUnusedParameters();
        // compile function.
        compile();
    }
    
    public Map execute(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, SQLBooking booking, SQLPerson[] presenters) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // pass in input parameter objects.
        params.put("pi_booking", booking);
        params.put("pi_presenters", new SQLPersonArray(presenters));
        // execute function.
        return super.execute(params);
    }   
}
```

and `SQLPersonArray` is simply an array wrapper for `AbstractSqlTypeValue`:

```
public class SQLPersonArray extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {
    private SQLPerson[] sqlPersonArr;
    // constructor.
    public SQLPersonArray(SQLPerson[] sqlPersonArr){
        this.sqlPersonArr = sqlPersonArr;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection connection, int sqlType, String typeName)
            throws SQLException {
        ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor(typeName, connection);
        return new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, connection, sqlPersonArr);
    }
}
```

The Oracle function and types are simply defined as:

```
function create_booking (
     pi_booking      in    booking_typ  
    ,pi_presenters   in    person_tbl_typ default null
    ,po_return       out   return_typ
  ) return integer;

create or replace type booking_typ force as object (
     booking_id          varchar2(60)
    ,room_name           varchar2(500)
    ,start_date          varchar2(20)
    ,duration            varchar2(20)
    ,constructor function booking_typ return self as result
  ) not final;

create or replace type person_tbl_typ as table of person_typ;

create or replace type "PERSON_TYP" force as object (
     id                  varchar2(50)   
    ,name                varchar2(50)
    ,constructor function person_typ return self as result
  ) not final;
```

Now, when I do this inside `BookingDaoJdbc.createBooking()`:

```
SQLBooking booking = ...;
SQLPerson[] presenters = ...,
CreateBookingFunction bookingCreator = new CreateBookingFunction(jdbcTemplate, "create_booking");
Map<String, Object> result = bookingCreator.execute(jdbcTemplate, booking, presenters);
```

I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` when it hits `bookingCreator.execute(...)`.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at oracle.sql.OracleSQLOutput.writeString(OracleSQLOutput.java:144)
    at test.mybookingsystem.model.SQLBooking.writeSQL(SQLBooking.java:100)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.toSTRUCT(STRUCT.java:500)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8729)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8829)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:4992)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
    at test.mybookingsystem.access.dao.BookingDaoJdbc.createBooking(BookingDaoJdbc.java:161)
    at test.mybookingsystem.service.BookingServiceImpl.createBooking(BookingServiceImpl.java:566)
    ...
```

I know that `SQLPerson[] presenters` can be an empty array sometimes, but is that really why this causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` is trying access the first object of an empty array? I guess it is not that stupid, is it?

---

Note 1) For people who may not have noticed, `StoredProcedure.execute()` is a method from Spring. It is not written by me, so I have no control over what happens within that method.

Note 2) This is definition of `StoredProcedure.execute()` in case of someone wants to find out:

```
    /**
     * Execute the stored procedure. Subclasses should define a strongly typed
     * execute method (with a meaningful name) that invokes this method, populating
     * the input map and extracting typed values from the output map. Subclass
     * execute methods will often take domain objects as arguments and return values.
     * Alternatively, they can return void.
     * @param inParams map of input parameters, keyed by name as in parameter
     * declarations. Output parameters need not (but can) be included in this map.
     * It is legal for map entries to be {@code null}, and this will produce the
     * correct behavior using a NULL argument to the stored procedure.
     * @return map of output params, keyed by name as in parameter declarations.
     * Output parameters will appear here, with their values after the
     * stored procedure has been called.
     */
    public Map execute(Map inParams) throws DataAccessException {
        validateParameters(inParams.values().toArray());
        return getJdbcTemplate().call(newCallableStatementCreator(inParams), getDeclaredParameters());
    }
```

and here is the doc about `StoredProcedure`: [org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure](http://javadox.com/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html)
Under `public Map<String,Object> execute(Map<String,?> inParams)` it says it `throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` but does not mention about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question. And what is SQLPersonArray?

Comment: if that array is empty, and you try to access the first (non-existing) element of it, what exactly do you think is going to happen? Yes, that seems to be exactly what your problem is

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry, details added.

Comment: @Stultuske It is not me who is trying to access it... I have no control inside Spring's `StoredProcedure.execute()`

Comment: @user2526586 so this: at test.mybookingsystem.access.dao.BookingDaoJdbc.createBooking(BookingDaoJdbc.java:161)
    is not in your code? I'm fairly sure that isn't a spring package. has it occurred to you to NOT call that method if presenters is empty?

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, I am not getting your point. `BookingDaoJdbc.createBooking()` is my code.   I DO want to call `CreateBookingFunction.execute()` even if `presenters` is empty, as the oracle function is designed to accept empty array. What puzzle me is why `StoredProcedure.execute()` (or its dependency objects) is trying to access elements inside `presenters` even when the array is empty.

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace, `test.mybookingsystem.model.SQLBooking.writeSQL(SQLBooking.java:100)
` is involved. Please add the code for `SQLBooking` to your question.

Comment: @user2526586 according to the stacktrace you posted, that line is where the problem occurs. after the update, it points indeed to SQLBooking.java -> 100. If you want us to help you understand your stacktraces, posting only partial stacktraces won't really do you any good

Comment: The error suggests that `presenters` is an empty array, but at least one is expected. You need to show the code of `test.mybookingsystem.model.SQLBooking.writeSQL`. Likely you should not call `OracleSQLOutput.writeString` with an empty array (or string) in that code.